# Get Sum of quantities from multiple tables?

Tags: sql

I have at least 8 tables from where I need to match the customer name and fetch the quantities and get the sum of all the quantities fetched from these 8 tables. I am trying to write a code which will ignore the customer whose sum of quantities is zero.

For an example lets take two tables purchase_sugar and sales_sugar I have tried a lot of queries but only this one is returning some result which is wrong.

```
SELECT sum(purchase_sugar.qty + sales_sugar.qty) AS Total_Amount from purchase_sugar inner join sales_sugar on purchase_sugar.supplier = sales_sugar.customer WHERE purchase_sugar.supplier = "+str(x.id)+"
```

The Table structures are like:
purchase_sugar have two columns supplier and qty.
And sales_sugar have structure like customer and qty.

How can I get the SUM of QUANTITIES of these tables if I provide one name and search it through these tables and get the quantities. The other thing is that I dont want the customer to be found in all the tables. If it is found in one table we should just get the quantity from that one table and for that reason I don't think that JOIN is useful or may be i am wrong.

Comment: your question is not clear  .. add a proper data sample  .. and the expected  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take care of the situation where a supplier/customer is not in all the tables, you can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select name, sum(p_qty) as sum_p, sum(s_qty) as sum_s,
       sum(p_qty) + sum(s_qty)
from ((select ps.supplier as name, ps.qty as p_qty, 0 as s_qty
       from  purchase_sugar ps 
      ) union all
      (select ss.customer as name, 0, ss.qty 
       from sales_sugar ss
      ) 
     ) s
group by name;
```

Notes:

- This query gets results for all names.  You can use a `where` clause to restrict the results to one `name`.
- You don't have to split the quantities into two (or eight) different columns, if you just want the overall sum.
- You can aggregate before the `union all`, but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

you should JOIN the sum and not sum the join

```
select t1.purchase_sum + sales_sum as Total_Amount 
from (
  select  purchase_sugar.supplier, sum(purchase_sugar.qty) as purchase_sum 
  from  purchase_sugar 
  group by  purchase_sugar.supplier 
) t1 
inner join  (
  select  sales_sugar.customer, sum(sales_sugar.qty) as sales_sum 
  from  sales_sugar 
  group by  sales_sugar.customer
) t2 on t1.supplier = t2.customer and t1.supplier = "+str(x.id)+"
```